# Angular js Dynamic Grid Header

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ng-grid, ng-bind

Here i want to dynamically update the display name or field of grid headers according to any user input value.

```
  <html ng-app="myApp">  
    <head lang="en">
     <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Getting Started With ngGrid Example</title>  
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ng-grid.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="ng-grid-1.3.2.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
   var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
  app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                {name: "Enos", age: 34}];
   $scope.gridOptions = { 
    data: 'myData',
       columnDefs: [{field: 'name', displayName: 'Name'},
                 {field:'age', displayName:'Age', cellTemplate: '<div ng-class="{red: row.getProperty(col.field) > 40}"><div class="ngCellText">{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</div></div>'}]
    };
  });
      </script>
         </head>
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now my requirement is:-

IN HTML There would be something like

A Dropdown in which there are my All Grid Headers value.
ANd corresponding there would be a input box

When user select any particular grid header from dropdown, then corresponding input value get mapped to that header , and my grid get also updated according to modified header.

- Guys please help me, i am really get stuck in doing this in angular
  and this is really very important for me

Comment: Haven't use ng-grid, but perhaps modifying the `$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs` array when thing changes is what you want?  You can do `$scope.$watch` on scope variable linked to the dropdown box and perform this changes in the watch callback?

Comment: In my grid there are two fields **1- name  2- age,**  Now  i  want to show a dropdown in html ,which contains the value of all field name....                      NOw suppose any user has selected name from the dropdown and he wants to change this value to Firstname.(there would be input box respective to dropdown).       Now i want when user input Firstname in input box then i want to update my grid columns to 1- Firstname 2- age

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the following example...

In the example, I am watching the changes on the select drop down, as well as watching the changes to the new field name.  When the name change, it will rebuild the ng-grid column using `self.gridOptions.ngGrid.buildColumns()`.

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
  
  angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('myCtrl', myCtrl);
  
  myCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$log'];
  function myCtrl($scope, $log) {
    var self = this;
    self.myData = [
      {name: "Moroni", age: 50},
      {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
      {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
      {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
      {name: "Enos", age: 34}
    ];
   
    self.selectedColumn = null;
    self.selectedFieldName = null;
    
    $scope.$watch(function() { return self.selectedColumn; },
      function(newValue, oldValue) {
        $log.info(oldValue, newValue);
        self.selectedFieldName = newValue.displayName;
      }
    );
    
    $scope.$watch(function() { return self.selectedFieldName; },
      function(newValue, oldValue) {
        self.selectedColumn.displayName = newValue;
        self.gridOptions.ngGrid.buildColumns();
      }
    );

    self.columnDefs =  [
        {field: 'name', displayName: 'Name'},
        {field:'age', displayName:'Age', cellTemplate: '<div ng-class="{red: row.getProperty(col.field) > 40}"><div class="ngCellText">{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</div></div>'}
      ];
    
    $scope["vm"] = self;
    
    self.gridOptions = { 
      data: 'vm.myData',
      columnDefs: self.columnDefs
    };
  }

}());
```

```css
.gridStyle {
    border: 1px solid rgb(212,212,212);
    height: 300px
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-grid/2.0.11/ng-grid.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-grid/2.0.11/ng-grid.debug.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">
  <select ng-options="column.field for column in vm.columnDefs" ng-model="vm.selectedColumn"></select>  
  <input type="text" ng-model="vm.selectedFieldName">
  
  <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="vm.gridOptions"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Thamks Jimmy, This was awesome :)